# jQuery Multiple Append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to append multiple values from an input, curious on how I can dry the append code. Possibly into a function, thanks!

```
    var $inputFirst = $('input:first').val();
    var $inputSecond = $('input:second').val();
    $('ul').append('<li>' + $inputFirst + '</li>');
    $('ul').append('<li>' + $inputSecond+ '</li>');
```

Comment: `$('ul').append($('<li/>').text($inputFirst));`

Comment: updated my answer for many inputs.

Comment: check my answer i have created a demo..and you can have any number of inputs and you can specify whether particular input's value should append to ul or not with providing class.thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
$(':input').each(function(i){
    $('ul').append('<li>'+$(':input').eq(i).val()+'</li>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have same number of `input` and `li`. You can iterate through the `li` and append the corresponding input value it.

```
inputs = $('input');
$('ul li').each(function(){
    $this).append(inputs.eq($this).index()));
});
```

**Note** As a additional note you are using tag that will effect the whole page. It might include the element you do not want to be part of this. So use class or some other attributes to access both `li` and `input` elements.

```
inputs = $('.class-of-input');
$('.class-of-ul li').each(function(){
    $this).append(inputs.eq($this).index()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i have created example for you on jsfiddle:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#createLI").click(function() {
        var lis = "";
        $(".forLI").each(function() {
            var vl = $(this).val();
            lis += "<li>" + vl + "</li>"
        });

        $("ul").append($(lis));
    });
});
```

working example link:http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/166/

we are using class to filter the input so it will select all the inputs while creating LI tags.

in above example you can have any number of input boxes.
just provide a class 'forLI' to input boxes it will append there text values to ul as li.

we can not select value like this `$('input:second').val();` you can use `$('input:eq(1)').val();`

thanks